# Mostrar AlertDialog solamente si la actividad o contexto está activa

Tags: android

Tengo un alertDialog personalizado con un layout, quisiera mostrar la alerta solamente si la actividad o contexto está activa, la aplicación que tengo que tiene Crashlytics implementado y ha detectado algunas veces que se cae en esa parte(a la hora de mostrar la alerta), el error que aparece es este: **This crash is usually caused by your app trying to display a dialog using a previously-finished Activity as a context**

He buscado en Stackoverflow para saber cuando una actividad está activa y me he encontrado varias respuestas, pero algunas personas comentan que no es confiable y cosas así, por eso pongo mi pregunta acá.

Este es un dialogo personalizado que tengo, posee un viewPager dentro, a nivel funcional es correcto, pero Crashlytics detecta algunas veces que se cae a la hora de mostrar el dialogo.

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpgradeSegmentActivity.this);
    View view = View.inflate(UpgradeSegmentActivity.this, R.layout.dialog_tutorial_mobis, null);
    builder.setView(view);

    alertTutoriales = builder.create();

    TutorialesMobiPagerAdapter adapter = new TutorialesMobiPagerAdapter(UpgradeSegmentActivity.this);
    ViewPager pager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    view.findViewById(R.id.ll_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertTutoriales.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertTutoriales.show();
```

Entonces resumiendo, mi pregunta sería **¿Cómo verificar que la actividad o contexto está activa y recién mostrar el dialogo?**

¿Es confiable usar **"MyActivity.this!=null?**

Comment: A mí me ha pasado pero de manera distinta. Tal vez mi experiencia te ayude con alguna idea. En ocasiones he tenido un proceso de fondo o async task que dependiendo del resultado me muestra un AlertDialog pero si el proceso async task no ha terminado y el usuario se sale de la actividad cuando el async task responda ya no tiene una actividad valida para mostrar el dialogo y muestra un error similar. Particularmente yo he usado esta condición y en ciertas ocasiones me ha funcionado bien `if(mActivity.isFinishing())` si es true la actividad va a cerrarse por lo tanto no muestro el dialogo

Comment: Hola @GustavoMora, un caso que me ha pasado es igual al tuyo,
con `isFinishing` te refieres a usarlo así:
`if(!mActivity.isFinishing()){
mDialog.show();
}`

Comment: Si, ósea mientras la actividad no se este cerrando o este cerrada que se muestre el dialogo.

Comment: Ok, gracias por el aporte @GustavoMora, usaré eso por ahora.

Answer (score -1):

Lo mejor sería asegurar que la `Activity` que determina el contexto del `AlertDialog` no esta finalizando o en proceso de finalización mediante  [isFinishing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) :

```
if(!UpgradeSegmentActivity.this.isFinishing()){
    //Muestra AlertDialog.
    alertTutoriales.show();
}
```

> [isFinishing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) Verifica si la Activity esta en proceso de
>   finalización.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, qué tan confiable es usar esto?

Comment: @JorgeRequez es un método de una clase del propio SDK que asegura determinar si la Activity esta en proceso de destrucción. Por medio de este método puedes validar mostrar o no el AlertDialog

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.